# Angularjs and ng-grid: how handle checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

in angulajs i have a ng-grid that i fill with data returned from a server. The field "Active" is a boolean so i have make a template to show a checkbox:

```
$scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData', enableCellSelection: true,
                       enableRowSelection: false, enableCellEdit: true,
                       columnDefs: [{ field: 'Id', displayName: 'Id', visible: false },
                                    { field: 'Name', displayName: 'Name', enableCellEdit: true },
                                    { field: 'Active', displayName: 'Active', enableCellEdit: true, cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.entity.Active" >' }]
```

Now, when i edit some cell, i want save back to the database the edited row and so i handle the ngGridEventEndCellEdit:

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function (data) {
   ....
}
```

event. In effect when i edit the cell "Name" the above handler is called but when i check/uncheck the checkbox Active, that event isn't called.
How can i emit the ngGridEventEndCellEdit when i check/uncheck the checkbox? Or how can handle that?

Comment: would an ng-change function in the checkbox element work?

Comment: i think it could work but i have two function to handle the edit? (one handler is $scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function (data) that is called when i edit, for example, the Name cell, and another handler that is called when i click the checkbox?

Comment: what is in the $scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function (data) {}) function ?

Comment: data is the edited data passed by the ng-grid to the custom handler

Answer (score 1):

What about emitting ngGridEventEndCellEdit from the checkbox ng-change function?

```
ng-change="emitEndCellEdit()"
```

with

```
$scope.emitEndCellEdit = function() { $scope.$emit('ngGridEventEndCellEdit') }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add ng-change="edit(row)" to your cell template. Handle all your stuff inside $scope.edit function. You should receive clicked grid data as a parameter.

Comment: So i have a function $scope.edit to handle the check/uncheck on the checkbox and $scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function (data) when i edit the other cells?

Comment: Look at klode answer. I was thinking about similar.